# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT student.studnt_id,student_onfo.student_name,subject,marks  
FROM `student` 
INNER JOIN 'student_info' ON student.studnt_id=student_info.studnt_id 
ORDER BY student.studnt_id
```

when i fire this query it is showing me this error

Comment: `student_onfo` seems wrong and you need to wrap table names in backticks: ` not single quotes

Comment: @ Pekka 웃  its working fine

Comment: This is a really stupid title for a question - especially because ~90% of all errors in MySQL have that message.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT student.studnt_id,student_info.student_name,subject,marks  
FROM `student` 
INNER JOIN `student_info` ON student.studnt_id=student_info.studnt_id 
ORDER BY student.studnt_id
```

Just try this Query.

You have Spell Mistakes here:-

**`student_onfo.student_name` -> `student_info.student_name`**

**'student_info' -> `student_info`**

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
      s.studnt_id
    , si.student_name
    , subject
    , marks  
FROM student AS s
JOIN student_info AS si ON s.studnt_id = si.studnt_id 
ORDER BY s.studnt_id
```

Comment: If this answer fully suit you, please, approve it.